# Where can I start c++ for applications in multiple OS?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wanna make an simple GUI application that work on at least Windows and Gnome Linux. I know c-like programming. now what compiler/application can I use for this purpose? Microsoft Visual Studio is work only for Windows Applications. And where I can learn more about these type of software development? I need some advanced advises. thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627127/writing-cross-platform-c-code-windows-linux-and-mac-osx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984609/compiling-for-mac-linux-on-windows

Comment: @joverboard: i think you dont get what |\/|R3zaM wants exactly.

Comment: @MaziarBouali I posted the links as additional reading about cross-platform and the notion that MSVS can't be used for Linux distributions, which is addressed especially in the second and third links.  They provide options and understanding, but not a direct answer, hence the comment rather than answer.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM: if any answer is useful, click on tick and make it green (mark best answer)

Comment: @joverboard: you're right, sorry for my haste ;)

Comment: Do you want "write-once, compile-anywhere", or do you want "write-once, run-anywhere"? The latter is not really possible in pure C++.

Comment: @joverboard Thank you for your links. I worked in some projects in php for cross-platform and multiple Web Server. I only need to know how advanced programmers make cross-platform GUI applications? And what tools they use? what IDE and compilers they use mostly. All programmers I know use Microsoft Visual Studio (that they learn in university) and don't care about cross-platform. thanks for your advises

Comment: @rubenvb I wanna write once (if it is possible) and compile anywhere. and wanna an advanced explicit IDE/Framework for doing this. that is most near pure c++

Comment: @joverboard thanks. Are you know for example what IDE/Framework/Compiler Firefox developers use? It must be something like simple editor. I really wanna to know what tools developers of a big cross-platform application use.

Comment: @IVIR3zaM MDN has this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Windows_Build_Prerequisites as a developer pre-requisite guide.  I would say (coming from a game/mobile prospective) that the main considerations with going cross-platform would be that your intrinsic code be as platform-independent as possible, with calls to functions that are platform specific. First link I gave discusses methods of platform macros in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Qt Framework](http://qt.nokia.com/) is probably your best bet.  Qt has a write once compile anywhere methodology so most of the time you shouldn't have to change code between different operating systems.  They do have their own IDE but I believe they have a plugin for integrating with visual studio as well.

Comment: is it support for iOS and Android? I know it must absolutely work with Symbian :-) . I saw their website and didn't see anything about iOS and Android.

Comment: It doesn't look like Qt has official Android support yet but there is a port in development called [necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/).  Qt has mentioned it in their blog so they are probably supporting that project.

Answer (score 2):

[Nokia Qt Framework](http://qt.nokia.com) is the best choice for you

Answer (score 2):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org) is also for you. It supports Windows, OS X, Linux and UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said this, but the Nokia QT framework is a great place to start.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29#Platforms is all of the platforms that your GUI would work in.